Derivation of the relationship between state-value function and action-value function in SAC
Below is the relationship between state-value function and action-value function based on the source: https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/sac.html

$$H(P) = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim P}[-\log P(x)].$$
In entropy-regularized reinforcement learning, the agent gets a bonus reward at each time step proportional to the entropy of the policy at that time step. This changes the RL problem to:
$$\pi^* = \arg \max_{\pi} \mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi}\left[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t\Bigl(R(s_t, a_t, s_{t+1}) + \alpha H (\pi(\cdot | s_t))\Bigr)\right],$$
where $\alpha > 0$ is the trade-off coefficient. (Note: we’re assuming an infinite-horizon discounted setting here, and we’ll do the same for the rest of this page.) We can now define the slightly-different value functions in this setting. $V^{\pi}$ is changed to include the entropy bonuses from every time step:
$$V^{\pi}(s) = \mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi}\left[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t \Bigl(R(s_t, a_t, s_{t+1}) + \alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s_t))\Bigr)\ \Big|\ s_0{=}s\right].$$
$Q^{\pi}$ is changed to include the entropy bonuses from every time step except the first:
$$Q^{\pi}(s,a) = \mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi}\left[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t R(s_t, a_t, s_{t+1}) + \alpha\sum_{t=1}^\infty \gamma^t H(\pi(\cdot|s_t))\ \Big|\ s_0{=}s, a_0{=}a\right].$$
With these definitions, $V^{\pi}$ and $Q^{\pi}$ are connected by:
$$V^{\pi}(s) = \mathbb{E}_{a \sim \pi}\left[Q^\pi(s, a)\right] + \alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s)).$$

Question: How is the derivation of the relationship between action-value function and state-value function given in the last line?

This relation is from the definition of action value function such as that defined in Sutton's RL book page 58.

we define the value of taking action $a$ in state $s$ under a policy $\pi$, denoted
$q_{\pi}(s, a)$, as the expected return starting from $s$, taking the action $a$, and thereafter following policy $\pi$

Thus in general following your reference's notation we have the obvious equational relation between state and action value functions of the same state as $V^{\pi}(s)=Q^{\pi}(s, \pi(s))=\mathbb{E}_{a \sim \pi}[Q^{\pi}(s, a))]$.
For SAC we need to add an additional policy's entropy bonus from every timestep for both state and action value functions, except the first timestep for action value function as your reference mentions since the entropy bonus is associated with the uncertainty of the policy when choosing among possible actions, but when we condition on having taken a specific action $a$ for $Q^{\pi}(s, a)$, we no longer consider the uncertainty of the policy at $s$ which has already been resolved by taking action $a$. Therefore we have to add the additional entropy bonus at state $s$ at the RHS to balance above equation as $V^{\pi}(s)=\mathbb{E}_{a \sim \pi}[Q^{\pi}(s, a))] + \alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s))$.

A great intuitive answer was provided by @cinch; I will provide an answer based on notation conversion. First, note that the sampled trajectory $\tau$ does not include $s_0$ because $s_0{=}s$ by definition of $V^\pi(s)$. We write out the first few terms of $\tau$ for clarity, condense $R(s_t, a_t, s_{t+1})$ into $R_t$, and distribute $\gamma^t$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V^{\pi}(s) &= \mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi}\left[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t \Bigl(R(s_t, a_t, s_{t+1}) + \alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s_t))\Bigr)\ \Big|\ s_0{=}s\right], \hspace{10em}\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{(a_0, r_0, s_1,\ \ldots) \sim \pi}\left[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t \Bigl(R_t + \alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s_t))\Bigr)\ \Big|\ s_0{=}s\right],\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{(a_0, r_0, s_1,\ \ldots) \sim \pi}\left[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t R_t + \sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t\Bigl(\alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s_t))\Bigr)\ \Big|\ s_0{=}s\right].\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Next, we use the fact that the expectation is not taken over $s_0{=}s$, allowing us to change the index of summation and move the entropy term $\alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s))$ outside of the expectation.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 &= \mathbb{E}_{(a_0, r_0, s_1,\ \ldots) \sim \pi}\left[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t R_t + \left(\sum_{t=1}^\infty \gamma^t\Bigr(\alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s_t))\Bigr)\right) + \alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s_0))\ \Big|\ s_0{=}s\right],\hspace{2.5em}\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{(a_0, r_0, s_1,\ \ldots) \sim \pi}\left[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t R_t + \alpha\sum_{t=1}^\infty \gamma^t H(\pi(\cdot|s_t))\ \Big|\ s_0{=}s\right] + \alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s)).\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We continue by splitting the expectation of $\tau = (a_0, r_0, s_1, \ldots)$ into an expectation over $a_0$ and an expectation over $(r_0, s_1, \ldots)$. Note that the expectation over $a_0$ is equivalent to the expectation over $a$ sampled from $\pi(\cdot|s)$ because $s_0{=}s$. Finally, we simplify using the definition of $Q^\pi(s, a)$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&= \mathbb{E}_{a_0 \sim \pi(\cdot | s_0)}\left[\mathbb{E}_{(r_0, s_1,\ \ldots) \sim \pi}\left[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t R_t + \alpha\sum_{t=1}^\infty \gamma^t H(\pi(\cdot|s_t))\ \Big|\ s_0{=}s, a_0\right]\right] + \alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s)),\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{a \sim \pi(\cdot | s)}\left[\mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi}\left[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t R_t + \alpha\sum_{t=1}^\infty \gamma^t H(\pi(\cdot|s_t))\ \Big|\ s_0{=}s, a_0{=}a\right]\right] + \alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s)),\hspace{-2.5em}\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{a \sim \pi(\cdot | s)}\left[Q^\pi(s, a)\right] + \alpha H(\pi(\cdot|s)),\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
as desired.
